# C# String Concatenation inside a loop

Tags: c#, loops, concatenation

I started this year studying IT and i got a question regarding C#.
I was tasked to print an N amount of random numbers and then add them together.
I am saving my random numbers in an array and then i have to print it.
When I run the code the "Calculating the result of: " keeps popping every time i print a number:

```cs
int[] numbers = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    int num = rnd.Next(101, 10000);
    numbers[i] = num;
    sum = sum + num;
    
    Console.Write("Calculating the result of:" + Convert.ToString(numbers[i]) + " + ");
}
```

Is there an efficient way to print the numbers in the same loop having the starting text only once?

Comment: You don't need `Convert.ToString` at all. You can use an interpolated string instead which is much more readable: `Console.WriteLine( $"Calculating the result of {numbers[i]}" );`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You'll be able to do that you want with the [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) method:

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
   int num = rnd.Next(101, 10000);
   numbers[i] = num;
   sum = sum + num;
}

Console.Write("Calculating the result of: " + string.Join(" + ", numbers));
```

Comment: Because you did not add the code, as an example, to your answer.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks! apparently if i move it out of the loop it works!

Answer (score 1):

Just print the message before the loop so it doesn't repeat itself.

```cs
int[] numbers = new int[10];
Console.Write("Calculating the result of:");

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    int num = rnd.Next(101, 10000);
    numbers[i] = num;
    sum = sum + num;
            
    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(numbers[i]) + " + ");
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but still i have a problem with the "+" that has to be printed every after number except the last one.

Comment: It is unclear why you have a problem with the "+" to be printed for every number except the last one. If you do not want it add an extra line: `if (i<number.Length-1) Console.Write(" + ");`, and remove the + from the other line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
    Console.Write("Calculating the result of:");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = rnd.Next(101, 10000);
        numbers[i] = num;
        sum = sum + num;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
    {            
        Console.Write(Convert.ToString(numbers[i]) + " + ");
    }


    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(numbers[numbers.Length - 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the printing-during-initial-loop a requirement? If it is, try

```cs
var prefix = "Calculating sum: ";
for (…) {
  …
  Console.Write(prefix);
  prefix = " + ";
  Console.Write(num.ToString());
}
```

Otherwise, given that performance is hardly a worry for exercise code like this, just do something like this after the loop:

```cs
Console.Writeline(string.Format("Calculation: {0} = {1}", string.Join(" + ", numbers.Select(n => n.ToString)), sum));
```

(On phone, and not sure now if `Console.Write` has an overload that makes the `string.Format` unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, simply put the Console.WriteLine outside your for loop. Consider using a [stringbuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) to store the numbers for presentation.

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = rnd.Next(101, 10000);
        numbers[i] = num;
        sum = sum + num;

        if(i != (numbers.Length - 1))
            sb.Append($"{numbers[i]} + ")
        else
            sb.Append($"{numbers[i]}")

    }
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculating the result of: {sb.ToString()}) sum: {sum}");
```

Good luck with your studies!